# Divide a range of values for each unique value

Tags: excel, vba, dataframe

I hope that someone can help me with this solution.

I have an Excel data frame with structure similar to the exemple below:

| Model | Year | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2010 | 2012 |
| B | 2013 | 2020 |

I need to split the range of years into a single row for each year.
Example below:

| Model | Year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2010 |
| A | 2011 |
| A | 2012 |
| B | 2013 |
| B | 2014 |
| B | 2015 |
| B | 2016 |
| B | 2017 |
| B | 2018 |
| B | 2019 |
| B | 2020 |

I couldn't think of anything to solve

Comment: Loop over the rows in the first dataset, and use a `For x = [startYear] to [endYear] ... Next x` loop to write each line in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

1. Your raw data on `SheetA` in `Columns A to C`
2. Your output data to be on `SheetB` in `Columns A to B`
3. Where `SheetB` already has the headers `Model` & `Year`

This will loop through all the Models on `SheetB` and output the unique `Model:Year` combinations starting in the next available row. Thus, if you already have some data on `SheetB`, this macro **will not** overwrite that data - instead it will add values beneath.

---

```
Sub mydearmacro()

Dim a_ws As Worksheet: Set a_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetA")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB")

Dim a_lr As Long, lr As Long
a_lr = a_ws.Range("A" & a_ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim model As String
Dim i As Long, y As Long, x As Long

For i = 2 To a_lr

    model = a_ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    start_year = a_ws.Range("B" & i) - 1
    y = a_ws.Range("C" & i) - a_ws.Range("B" & i) + 1
    lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 1 To y
        ws.Range("A" & lr + x).Value = model
        ws.Range("B" & lr + x).Value = start_year + x
    Next x
    
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]